# Is it possible to read other application's localstorage in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, browser

I know that

```js
this.storageService.setItem(...)
```

works fine to store the information in the key-value store for an angular application (example, in chrome, going to `Application Data` then `local storage` and I see, say `www.example.com`

Is there a way to view a different application/website's localstorage from inside my own angular app?

that is to say, if my angular app is hosted on `www.example.com` is it possible (and if so, how?) to view `www.foo.com`'s localstorage?

My feeling on this is 'No' because it seems like a security issue but I wanted to know if that's accurate. I didn't see anything in the docs about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local storage is available to any script on the same domain. If you want to gain access to local storage from another domain, then you will have to get that domain to host your script. That is by the way the basis for a cross site scripting attack on local storage. You are correct that it is a security by design that prevents domains from accessing each other's storage.